# Logo not redirecting to Home Page

Tags: react-native

I recently implemented a drawer menu from React Navigation into my app and I have a logo put onto it. I wanted the logo to be clickable so can link back to the home page.

I tried using the createDrawerNavigation component from React Navigation. I think the error has to do with poorly exporting the two constants but I'm unfamiliar with the proper syntax.

```
/*/ Drawer Menu /*/

const navigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Page1: Lander,
    Page2: Lander,
    Page3: Lander,
    Page4: Lander,
  },

  {
    contentComponent: (props) => ( 
      <SafeAreaView> 
        <Menu {...props}/> 
      </SafeAreaView> 
    )

  },
);
/*/ End of Drawer Menu /*/


/*/ Navigator Constants /*/
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Lander,
  },
},

  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    headerMode: 'none',

});

export default createAppContainer(navigator, AppNavigator);

/*/ End of Navigator Constants /*/


/*/Drawer Menu with the Drawer Items and Logo inside /*/

export default class Menu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>
            <Image source={require('../../Images/picture.png')} style = {styles.icon}/>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>


        <ScrollView style= {{backgroundColor: 'black', paddingLeft: '5%',}}>
          <DrawerItems {...this.props}  activeTintColor='#2196f3' activeBackgroundColor='rgba(0, 0, 0, .04)' inactiveTintColor='rgba(0, 0, 0, .87)' inactiveBackgroundColor='transparent' style={{backgroundColor: '#000000'}} labelStyle={{color: '#ffffff', fontSize:30,}}   />
        </ScrollView>

        )
    }
}
```

When I click on the logo, I don't receive an error message, however, it doesn't redirect anywhere.

Comment: try this.props.navigation.navigate('AppNavigator')

Comment: It doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're creating AppContainer wrong way,If you don't need two separate StackNavigator, a simple approach is create Home StackNavigator inside DrawerNavigator

```
    /*/ Drawer Menu /*/

const navigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeStackNavigator
    Page1: Lander,
    Page2: Lander,
    Page3: Lander,
    Page4: Lander,
  },

  {
    contentComponent: (props) => ( 
      <SafeAreaView> 
        <Menu {...props}/> 
      </SafeAreaView> 
    )

  },
);
/*/ End of Drawer Menu /*/


/*/ Navigator Constants /*/
const HomeStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Lander,
  },
},

  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    headerMode: 'none',

});

 export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

Comment: That helped clear most of the confusion I had with this. However, in order to make a clickable logo, I need to style a drawer item individually. Do you know how I could do this?

Comment: sorry I don't really understand your question, if you use contentComponent, you need to create each menu item yourself